# Why the surface of wet paper deforms after drying?

Tags: material-science, physical-chemistry

When I use liquid glue to stick one sheet of paper on the other then why it's surface becomes zig-zag/deformed (I couldn't find very good word for it).
First I thought that it's because of the air between two sheets but it happens even if I remove all the air between the two surfaces.
Sorry if it's very silly question as I couldn't find it anywhere on the internet.

This is not the very best picture but it is very similar to it

[image]

Comment: "Sorry if it's very silly question" - hey, if this is a silly question, then science was built on silly questions, so you're in good company

Comment: related question: https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/352714/can-wet-paper-completely-regain-its-strength-after-drying

Answer (score 22, accepted):

In the process of its manufacture, paper gets stretched *anisotropically* (more stretch in some directions than others) while at the same time the fibers that make up the sheet of paper get aligned with their long axies parallel to the direction the sheet had while moving through all the rollers, dryers, etc. in the paper factory. Then, after all that took place, the paper is baked to set up the glue that was mixed into the fibers to add strength to the sheet.

But that glue is soluble in water, and when the sheet gets wet it is allowed to relax and unstretch (more in some directions than in others) as well as swell up as the cellulose fibers rehydrate themselves.

This makes a wet sheet of paper do a variety of unexpected things which make it get corrugations, bulges, creases, buckling, and so on as the fibers are allowed to relieve their internal stresses. By the time the paper has dried out, it has "forgotten" its flatness.

Comment: [I've collected a variety of drying and related thin-film patterns from the literature (along with the interesting terms used to describe them)](http://john.maloney.org/Patterns/patterns.htm); as you note, the common element is essentially always minimization of the total strain energy by out-of-plane deflection.

Comment: Thank you for all the information. It is very helpful